# Static / Constant Loss for Convolutional Neural Network in Torch

Tags: machine-learning, lua, torch

I have a 1-D time series classification problem, and I have imported the data into Torch. I have written two different networks to learn the data. Each row is to be labelled as either a 1 or a 0.

**The problem is that the loss of the Convolutional Network does not fall after the first iteration**. It stays at *exactly* the same value, after iteration one. This is not true for the other network - a Logistic Regression. The loss of that network does fall over time.

Below is the ConvNet:

```
model = nn.Sequential()

for i = 1, iteration do
    model:add(nn.TemporalConvolution(1,1,3,1))
    model:add(nn.BatchNormalization(1))
    model:add(nn.ReLU())
    model:add(nn.TemporalMaxPooling(3,2))
    if i == iteration then
            model:add(nn.Sigmoid())
    end
end
```

Since the LogReg's loss does fall, I assume the problem is to do with the ConvNet itself, rather than anything else in the code.

Any advice would be much appreciated. I am happy to post more code if required.

Answer (score 1):

Usually if there is no improvement when minimizing the loss function the model is already at a local(global) minimum.

This can have several reasons, e.g. **learning-rate**, **regularization**, data does not fit to the model in some way ...
It's hard to say just based on the model.

Did you use the exact same code for training in LogReg?

You can check out this tutorial for some information about temporalConvolution:
http://supercomputingblog.com/machinelearning/an-intro-to-convolutional-networks-in-torch/

Comment: thanks for the link! i implemented the tutorial in the link and it works fine. however my own ConvNet is still failing to update ... :-/